# Is there a way to follow the curve of a polynomial at a fixed speed?

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm trying to follow the curve of a polynomial between $x=0$ and $x=1$ at a fixed speed using the arc length formula:

$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$

I've gotten around the square root problem by approximating it with a Taylor series expansion, which I can take the indefinite integral of.

The last problem I can't find a solution to is finding or approximating the inverse function of the indefinite integral.

I know that the indefinite integral is a polynomial with no critical points and a one-to-one relationship.

Any thoughts, ideas, tricks, or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Sorry for not being clear, I never had any formal calculus classes. Because the arc length formula outputs the length of a curve from a to b (in my case from $0$ to $1$), I thought that I could find the position along the curve were the length of the curve was equal to a specific value so I could "travel" along or "follow" the curve for a set distance.

Comment: I do not know exactly what you mean. The derivative of the arc length formula gives you access to a measure of instantaneous speed for a particular x value. (think of physics where the derivative of a curve of an st-diagram gives you information about the particle's velocity). Do you have an example or something?

Comment: I don't think using a Taylor series expansion to integrate--which itself creates a Taylor series--is _"getting around the square root problem"_.  Sure, you can integrate with a Taylor series but the resulting Taylor series (the indifinite integral) is unlikely to reveal some nice function.

Comment: Let me see if I understood. You want to find a trajectory $\mathbf{r}(t),\ t \in [t_0,t_1]$ such that: $\mathbf{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t))=(x(t),f(x(t)))$; $||\frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt} ||=c$ (constant); $\mathbf{r}(t_0)=(0,f(0))$, $\mathbf{r}(t_1)=(1,f(1))$, where $f$ is a polynomial . Is that right?

Comment: @P.Gomes I think that's the only interpretation that makes sense. The integral is trivial for constant and linear polynomials. For a quadratic polynomial finding the antiderivative is tricky but manageable (a typical antiderivative involves $\text{arsinh} x$ but solving for the inverse is amounts to solving a transcendental equation, and there is not closed-form inverse in terms of elementary functions. The situation is even worse for cubic and higher-degree polynomials, for which the antiderivative involves elliptic/hypergeometric functions.

Comment: The Taylor series for the inverse of the indefinite integral will be invertible as a Taylor series, and this is a standard exercise, but one shouldn't expect to be able to recover anything closed-form from that inverse. More generally, one can find a closed-form solution for this problem ("parameterization by arc length") only for very few curves.